# multiple select dropdowns - 'chaining' actions/validation from one to the next till 'complete' using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

Apologies for the title as I couldn't think of a better way to describe this.  On a page I have multiple select dropdowns.  The choice of one can affect the second, the choice of the second can affect the third, and so on... with a final action being done at the 'end' using the selected values of all three.  I came up with the following which does seem to work, but I have to believe there is a better way to handle this.

Pseudo code, but you should get the idea.  I would be using this in various ways such as displaying a table of data or displaying a chart based given the values of each select in 'complete()'.

**html**

```
<select id="one" name="one">
    some options here
</select>

<select id="two" name="two">
    some options here
</select>

<select id="three" name="three">
    some options here
</select>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#one').on("change", function (e) {
    two();
});

$('#two').on("change", function (e) {
    three();
});

$('#three').on("change", function (e) {
    complete();
});

function one() {
    ...maybe change options of two or something else
    $('#two').trigger('change');
}

function two() {
    ...maybe change options of three or something else
    $('#two').trigger('change');
}

function three() {
    ...do something
    $('#three').trigger('change');
}

function complete() {
    ...use values from all three to do something
}
```

**More information added for clarity :**

No matter what select is changed I need to do 'checks' on it and every one after it till the complete action happens.  For example, if I changed 1 then I check it, then 2, then 3, then run complete.  If 2 is changed I check it, then 3, then run complete.  If 3 is changed I check it then run complete.

Example :  1 is changed to option value 'dogs' by the user, because dogs was selected in it I know to change the options in 2 to dog types, and since dog types are shown in 2 I change the options in three to colors... then I run complete.  Complete in this case would give me dogs, all types, all colors as the values.

Now, say they change 2 to a value of 'pit bull' as it is now an option available to them.  So I check its value and change 3 to only show options of all, white, and black then run complete.  Complete gives me dogs, pit bull, and all colors as the values.

What I am getting at is when any select is changed I might make changes on the selects after it based on that change - like they are all chained together - and I need to reach complete on each one.

I would be using this to show a table and/or chart based on the selections.  So on each change of any I check all the selections after it, get the values, and update the table/chart.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods.

```
<script>
  function complete() {
    jQuery( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
      var _this = jQuery(this);
      console.log("SELECT_BOX " + _this.attr('name') + ':' +_this.val());
    });
  }

  jQuery('select').on('change', function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    if(_this.next('select').length){
      //Here We are adding active class to the next select box, you can change as per requirement
      _this.next('select').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      //When you reach to the last select box
      complete();
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I get what you are doing here, but all this does is do something on the select after the one that was changed - not ALL of them after the one was changed.  I can't assume the user is going to physically change all of them.  Any that is changed needs to 'run through' the checks of all after it no matter what and run complete() at the end.